# No colors in PHP cli

Tags: php, linux, bash, centos, command-line-interface

I have on a remote linux (Centos) server with PHP 7.0.12 installed on it.
When i ssh to this server and run php commands such as:

- Composer actions
- Behat tests
- Symfony CLI commands
- Doctrine migratinos

All the output i see is in black and white, no colors at all appear (green for successful tests/ red for erros, etc.).

However, the linux bash itself , HAS colors (when doing 'ls' for example).
I didn't found nothing on this issue online, really hope someone here encountered this annoying issue and knows the cause.

Comment: this is not a programming question, its about the os, belongs on: http://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Maybe you right, but this issue occurs only on PHP output, so i suspected it have something to do with the PHP installation/configuraiton.

Comment: "When i ssh " so how is that php related?

Comment: @nogad Because he's running PHP scripts that normally produce output with colors in them.

Comment: Make sure your `TERM` environment variable is set correctly.

Comment: @Barmar it is set to 'xterm', which i guess is ok.

Comment: man! just answer the poor guy question.... some of you are so eager to follow rules... I'm happy to have the answer now ! thx dude for your question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found it! 'php-posix' package was needed for php to output colors in centos.
This was installed via this package: `php-process-7.0.12-2.el7.remi.x86_64`

Comment: This IS the answer ! man it's hard to track it. Mark it as answered

Comment: I'm upvoting, because I had the same problem on localhost and installing php7.1-posix + phpenmod fixed it, thanks!